# How can i replace daily x-axis labels with months but keep chart showing daily values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a chart from my dataframe (which has got daily data) and want the xlables to show up as months (covering all the daily data period).
For example if i have data from 2010-01-01 till 2010-12-31, i want 365 days data points, but in the x-axis i want just Jan, Feb, Mar, etc... each of those month covering the exact period of the corresponding days. Strugglling in getting this...

This is the DataFrame:

```
    Daily CP ROI S2     positive    Month   Day
Date                
2008-01-02  100087.000  True    January     2
2008-01-03  101967.000  True    January     3
2008-01-04  102167.000  True    January     4
2008-01-07  104004.000  True    January     7
2008-01-08  105192.000  True    January     8


pl_plot = pl_plot.set_index('Date')
figure(num=None, figsize=(20, 8), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.ylabel('USD', fontsize=18)
plt.rc('ytick',labelsize=16)
final_value = new_df_test.iloc[ei-2]['Daily_Compound_ROI']
roi = round(((final_value - very_init_budget)/very_init_budget)*100,3)
roi_s=str(roi)
plt_title_s = new_title+'\nPeriod: '+y_init_s+'-'+y_end_s+', (ROI: '+roi_s+'%)'
plt.title(plt_title_s, fontsize=24)
pl_plot['positive'] = pl_plot['Daily_Compound_ROI'] > 100000
pl_plot['Daily CP ROI S2'].plot(kind='bar', color=pl_plot.positive.map({True: '#5cb85c', False: 'r'}))
ax1 = plt.axes()
plt.rc('xtick',labelsize=14)
x_axis = ax1.axes.get_xaxis()
x_axis.set_visible(True)
```

I want to get something like the below (keep red color when value is below 100000 otherwise green color for the bar), but in the x-axis would like to see Jan, Feb, Mar, etc... without any separation between the months (and dont want to see each single day as i see right now).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6N4R.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please cut down your posted example to a [mcve], which reproduces your issue but is short, runs as is and includes nothing else hence is easily understandable.

Comment: E.g. you don't mention in your post anywhere that it is about a barplot, this _can_ be found somewhere in your code part. If you try to simply `plot` your data over your dates, the result should automatically show a resolution on the time axis which looks nice - hence your described problem doesn't even show up.

Comment: ok guys, sorry it is my first post, i will change it.

Comment: i want to show a barchart with daily timeframe (value) but in the x axis i want to show the months' names rather than the daily date. @SpghttCd is right below, but two things are missing from what i want: different color as explained above (just added this point sorry), and the months shouldn't be separated from each other. If possible woul dlove to keep the code above as i also automated the generation of dynamic title etc... not sure how to achieve the same with seaborn. Thanks a lot for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you could give [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) a try.

If you add a month- and day-column to your dataframe, you can make a barpot with monthly separated blocks of bars per day.

---

***Example:***

```
# import pandas as pd
# import numpy as np

# df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('15.8.2019', '27.11.2019'))
# df['Value'] = np.random.random(len(df))
# df['Month'] = df.index.month_name()
# df['Day'] = df.index.day

#                Value     Month Day
# 2019-08-15  0.813130    August  15
# 2019-08-16  0.850873    August  16
# 2019-08-17  0.728416    August  17
# 2019-08-18  0.326072    August  18
# 2019-08-19  0.880385    August  19
#              ...       ...  ..
# 2019-11-23  0.771801  November  23
# 2019-11-24  0.638811  November  24
# 2019-11-25  0.824542  November  25
# 2019-11-26  0.451075  November  26
# 2019-11-27  0.151469  November  27
```

given this dataframe, you could do

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.catplot(kind='bar', x='Month', y='Value', hue='Day', data=df, color='b', legend=False)
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, would it be possible to keep the months attached to each other without any separation? Something like this but with the x axis showing the months names... https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6N4R.png

Answer (score -1):

That looks quite strange as i am answering my own question.
Anyway i found the way:

```
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
sns.set(font_scale=1.5, style="whitegrid")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))
ax.bar(df.index.values, df['Daily CP ROI S2'].values, width=1, color=pl_plot.positive.map({True: '#5cb85c', False: 'r'}))
ax.set(#xlabel="Period", ylabel="USD", title=title1)
ax.title.set(fontsize=24)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%b"))
plt.show()
```

the above fixes the problem and what i get is the below:

[Chart as i wanted it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKwTY.png)

The only problem left is now i need to fit the title within the chart :) Will look after this, but if any suggestions, please go ahead! Thanks.

Comment: glad that your on your way. I still can't reproduce your code; however perhaps you can try `fig.suptitle(title1)` instead...? And possibly play around with `plt.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 1, .9x])`

Comment: fixed also this one with fig = ax.figure.savefig("/path/file.png", bbox_inches='tight')   . i can't tag the code in this post... not sure why...